# Getting password file entry for the current user

Tags: c++, passwd

I have this in my source code:

```
struct passwd* user_info = getpwnam("root");
```

Is there  anyway to change the "root" and my program will find the current user? For example if I am logged in with user root2 I want info for root2 and not for root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the user's uid with `getuid()` (form `unistd.h`) and pass it to `getpwuid()`.

Comment: "it's not working!" is not useful. What exactly is not working? How exactly did you write the code?

Comment: struct passwd* user_info = getpwnam(getuid());

Comment: @user776720: please re-read that answer, and the man page. `getpwnam` takes a string, `getuid` returns an uid which is not a string. The answer provides the right function to use with `getuid`.

Answer (score -1):

The following code will get the username in linux,

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::string name;
    name = system("whoami");
    cout << "Name is : " << name;
    cout << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `system()` returns the command's exit status, not it's standard output.

Comment: And you're not including the header for `system`, even if it somehow worked like that.

Comment: Also, this depends on the user having the `whoami` program somewhere in their path.